# how would you colorize specific jqgrid cell text

Tags: html, sql-server-2008, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have a stored procedure (sql server 2008) that returns the status of (4) different fields into a single column of a jqgrid, like Good/Bad/Good/Bad. What I would like to do is have the **Good** text display in Green and the **Bad** text display in Red. I could separate them into different columns and then set the color of each, but I prefer to have a single column. Can I set this value in the stored procedure, or wrap this in the class with html to do this?

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) for doing this like follwing.

```
{ name: 'status', index: 'status', formatter:colorFormatter}
```

**colorFormatter** function looks like following.

```
function colorFormatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
   var data = cellvalue.split('/');
   var length = data.length; 
   var new_format_value='', text, color, separator='/'; 

   for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {
       var text=data[i]; 
       text=='Good'?
           color='style="color:green;"':
           color='style="color:red;"';

       if(i==length-1) separator='';    

       new_format_value+='<span '+color+'>'+text+'</span>'+separator;
   }

   return new_format_value
}
```

JS Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/12221/

Comment: Thank you. This seems to wortk for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much JQGrid changed since I last touched it, but you could do something like:

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
url: 'yoururl',  
datatype: 'xml',
mtype: 'GET',
colNames:['id','category'],
....
gridComplete: function fireup(){
  jQuery('#list')
    .setCell('d1','kategorie', '', { 'font-weight': 'bold', background: '#ddf' }) 
    .setCell('d1','name', '', { 'font-weight': 'bold', background: '#ddf' })
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I believe that your code is setting the background color of the Cell and not the specific text, Good/Bad/Good where the Good should show in Green and the Bad should show in Red.

Comment: Yes, but you can just use "color: #efccef" instead of background. Important is the .setCell part that allows you to set css values for your cells.